# Make Solr automatically search by first suggestion in spell correction

Tags: solr

We're trying to use Solr to correct the spelling of certain tests in a search box. We found that it works like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/spell?q=badspelled&spellcheck=true
```

And it returns a set of suggested terms. But what we need is not a list of suggestions but that Solr makes a search directly using the first suggestion. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the "spellcheck.collate=true" parameter to your first search query and then use the "collation" value in the response to fire a second query with that value.

Example from the plugin page:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/spell?q=price:[80 TO 100] delll ultrashar&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.extendedResults=true&spellcheck.collate=true
```

This returns the suggestions:

```
<lst name="spellcheck">
  <lst name="suggestions">
    <lst name="delll">
      <int name="numFound">1</int>
      <int name="startOffset">18</int>
      <int name="endOffset">23</int>
      <int name="origFreq">0</int>
      <arr name="suggestion">
        <lst>
          <str name="word">dell</str>
          <int name="freq">2</int>
        </lst>
      </arr>
    </lst>
    <lst name="ultrashar">
      <int name="numFound">1</int>
      <int name="startOffset">24</int>
      <int name="endOffset">33</int>
      <int name="origFreq">0</int>
      <arr name="suggestion">
        <lst>
          <str name="word">ultrasharp</str>
          <int name="freq">2</int>
        </lst>
      </arr>
    </lst>
    <bool name="correctlySpelled">false</bool>
    <str name="collation">price:[80 TO 100] dell ultrasharp</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
```

Then fire another query with the suggested query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/spell?q=price:[80 TO 100] dell ultrasharp&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.extendedResults=true&spellcheck.collate=true
```

[SpellCheck collate](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#Collate_Results)

Comment: Is it possible to let Solr do that? Sending a second query looks like an overkill. Of course it's possible to write an HTTPHandler that at least fires the second query on the same node, but is it possible to get that second query witin Solr itself?